# Is it possible to disable Kinect support while playing Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, xbox-360, kinect

I've been playing the Xbox 360 version of Mass Effect 3 and since I have a Kinect attached to the system, the game automatically "uses" its functionality. That is, whenever I or anyone or anything else the room makes a noise, a small red microphone appears in the upper left-hand corner. This is pretty distracting, especially when it happens in the middle of an intense fight.

**Is there a way to turn this functionality off other than just unplugging the Kinect sensor?**

[image]

*(Sorry for the blurry picture. It's tricky taking a photo of your TV during a firefight with a controller in your hands.)*

Comment: Also annoying: When someone walking out the door yells 'shotgun!' as they head for their car.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable Kinect support:

- Pause the game
- Go to the "Options" menu
- Choose "Narrative"
- Move down to "Kinect Player Dialect" and choose "Disabled."

Back out of the menu, and you'll stop getting mic icons!  This also disables the icons in the center of the conversation wheel, for instance.